# Memory efficient sliding window sequence learning with TensorFlow

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, memory

I am training an auto-encoder network used to encodes multivariate time sequences over a large data set. I uploaded a fully working example as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Zwackelmann/970cf3958134f2f537145bcbf520517f).

Even though it is working, I have to decide between an extremely memory inefficient or a slow solution. And I would like to get my memory efficient solution faster.

In my memory inefficient setup I prepare the training set as in `plain_dataset`. I.e. by materializing sliding windows over the whole data set. (in my real training setup those are highly overlapping)

Instead I want to define my training set like in `idx_dataset` as a list of `(dataset_index, row_index, size)` - tuples. Before each training step this references are resolved and actual training example is compiled.

I converted the time series data set to a [RaggedTensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor) `rt` to be able to access the data in graph mode. Then I implemented the index resolution in `resolve_index_batch` as part of my `custom_fit` function.

My hope was that composing this training example is quite cheap compare to the actual training step but the throughput is almost half when using the index training set.

Any ideas how to make the `resolve_index_batch` function more efficient?

```
@tf.function
def resolve_index_batch(idx_batch):
    """
    param idx_batch: (32x3) int32 tensor. Each row containing [time_series_idx, row_idx, window_size] 
    """
    return tf.map_fn(fn=lambda idx: tf.slice(rt[idx[0]], [idx[1], 0], [idx[2], -1]), elems=idx_batch, fn_output_signature=tf.float32)

@tf.function
def train_step(batch):
    if mode == 'idx':
        # apply the conversion from indexes batch to data_series batch
        batch = resolve_index_batch(batch)

    # train on reversed time series
    batch_flip = tf.reverse(batch, [1])
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        m = model(batch, training=True)
        loss = loss_fun(batch_flip, m)
        grad = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)

    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, model.trainable_weights))
    return loss
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To speed up `resolve_index_batch`, use `tf.gather` to replace `tf.map_fn`. `tf.map_fn` is just a trap that many people fall into it and it performs very poorly in GPU. `tf.gather` is the correct way to vectorize your operations.

Example codes:

```
@tf.function
def resolve_index_batch_fast(idx_batch):
    """
    note that window length should be a constant, which is the case in your gist codes WINDOW_LEN = 14
    """
    batch_size = idx_batch.shape[0] #if batch size is constant, this line can be optimized as well
    return tf.gather(tf.gather(rt,idx_batch[:,0]),tf.tile(tf.range(window_length)[None,:],[batch_size,1])+idx_batch[:,1:2],batch_dims=1)
```

In my experimentation, it is at least multiple times faster than `resolve_index_batch` in GPU depending on the batch size. The larger the batch size, the larger the speedup. In CPU, `tf.map_fn` works fairly good though.

To compare the performance between plain approach vs index approach, it is not so meaningful to have data this small in which the entire `rt` can fit into the GPU memory. In practical and realistic problem size for deep learning, the entire `rt` should be much larger and can only reside in CPU memory or even SSD.

So first thing to do is to ensure `rt` is in CPU memory by doing this:

```
def series_ragged_tensor():
    with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
        rt = tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_lengths(tf.concat(data_series(), axis=0), [ser.shape[0] for ser in data_series()])
    return rt
```

Second, do data preparation in CPU asynchronously. Inside `def idx_dataset()`:

```
return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(arr).batch(32).map(resolve_index_batch).repeat().prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Third, move `resolve_index_batch` definition and `rt = series_ragged_tensor()` to the right place and make `train_step` the same for index mode and plain mode accordingly.

Comment: Your solution make a lot of sense. However on a fresh g4dn.xlarge GPU instance, I cannot verify that the solution is much faster than my original solution. I also repeated the experiment with fixed batch size and also with a concrete function (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#obtaining_concrete_functions). For this I had to slightly modify the line to `tf.gather(tf.gather(rt, idx_batch[:, 0]), tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(WINDOW_LEN), axis=0), [32, 1]) + tf.slice(idx_batch, [0, 1], [-1, 1]), batch_dims=1)`. However the plain approach is still outperforming the index approach.

Comment: I edited the answer regarding comparison between plain approach and index approach. Please see if it help.

Comment: I think applying the `resolve_index_batch` as a mapping in the data set initialization did the trick. Index and plain training performs almost identical now. Thanks a lot!